# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' with Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm very new to Angular and web development in general, and I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.codelord.net/2016/01/07/adding-the-first-angular-2-service-to-your-angular-1-app/), and I got as far as adding the angular2 scripts to my index.html file, but when I try to run the application, I get the `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'` on all my .js scripts, line 1:0, which seems fairly common.

The strange thing is, when I open these scripts through the console, they all open `index.html` instead of the actual .js file, even the angular2 ones.

Here's `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController">
    <p>Testing</p>
    <app></app>

    <script src="../../../node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.umd.js"></script>
    <script
        src="../../../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script
        src="../../../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-all.umd.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="hello.js"></script>
    <script src="refactor.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`hello.js`, taken from [this video](https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-2-say-hello-world-to-angular-2?series=angular-2-fundamentals):

```
import {bootstrap} from "../../../node_modules/angular2/platform/browser";
import {Component} from "../../../node_modules/angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector:'app',
    template:`<div>Hello World</div>`
})

class App{}

bootstrap(App);
```

And `refactor.js`, from the first tutorial mentioned:

```
var upgradeAdapter = new ng.upgrade.UpgradeAdapter();
angular.element(document.body).ready(function() {
  upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
});
```

**EDIT:** I couldn't run `ng-serve` because the project wasn't created with `ng new project`. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser";
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
```

instead of

```
import {bootstrap} from "../../../node_modules/angular2/platform/browser";
import {Component} from "../../../node_modules/angular2/core";
```

Moreover `angular2-all.umd.dev.js` is when you want to use ES5 to implement your Angular2 application. In this case you should use

```
var AppComponent = ng.core
    .Component({
        selector: 'app',
        template: '<div>Hello world</div>',
    })
    .Class({
        constructor: function (http) {
        }
    });
```

instead of the `@Component` decorator...

I think that you need to choose the technologies you want to use because it seems that you mixed several parts of them.

Here are samples for different technologies:

- ES5 only: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ki6e9KgsPaiHIxfhKH3E
- ES6 only: https://plnkr.co/edit/ymSUUCvG5NFvmCGqzj2r
- TypeScript: https://plnkr.co/edit/Rw4kOzKFbVosaoe7dRL1

Comment: I should have added this, my .js and index.html files are all on `src/main/resources/templates`, and my `node_modules` directory is in the same level as `src`. Should I still use `"angular2/platform/browser"`?

Comment: But the `angular2/platform/browser` is registered implicitly with `System.register`... No path here. Your problem I think is that you include ES5 Angular2 file and try to use TypeScript or ES6 when implementing your component... Which one do you want to use?

Comment: I don't know... I don't know the differences between those versions. I tried editing `hello.js` as you suggested but the problem persists

Comment: You need to make a choice ;-) I updated my answer with samples for each of them...